# Displaying an image in a sharepoint web part for sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint, spfx

I'm trying to create my own image gallery web part for sharepoint. 
Currently, i have an image showing on my local server, but when i look at the web part on my sharepoint site, it does not appear. I have made changes to the gulp file to try to correctly address this, however i have had no luck.

gulpfile.js

```
'use strict';

const gulp = require('gulp');
const build = require('@microsoft/sp-build-web');

build.addSuppression(`Warning - [sass] The local CSS class 'ms-Grid' is not camelCase and will not be type-safe.`);

build.configureWebpack.mergeConfig({
    additionalConfiguration: (generatedConfiguration) => {

    if (build.getConfig().production) {
        var basePath = build.writeManifests.taskConfig.cdnBasePath;
         if (!basePath.endsWith('/')) {
               basePath += '/';
         }
         generatedConfiguration.output.publicPath = basePath;
     }
    else {
          generatedConfiguration.output.publicPath = "/dist/";
      }   
    generatedConfiguration.externals = generatedConfiguration.externals.filter(name => !(["react", "react-dom"].includes(name))) 
    return generatedConfiguration;
    }
});
build.initialize(require('gulp'));
```

Demo.tsx:

```
export default class demo extends React.Component<IDemoProps, {}> {
  public render(): React.ReactElement<IDemoProps> {
    return (
      <div className={ styles.demo }>
        <div className={ styles.container }>
          <div className={ styles.row }>
            <div className={ styles.column }>

              <div className={ styles.imageGallery }>

              <span className={ styles.title }>Look at this Not Stupid Gallery!!</span>

              <div className={ styles.imageGalleryImages }>
                <img src={"/lib/webparts/demo/components/Images/Selfie4.jpg"} alt={"Selfie"}/>
                <p>MY PICTURE HERE!</p>
              </div>
              (..a lot of skipped, duplicated image divs)..
              <div className = { styles.title }>It knows you want a bigger view of a picture!</div>
              </div>
            </div>  
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

A couple pictures showing my image working in the lova/dev env, but not in sharepoint.
my image appears when viewing the web part from [this url (local)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSx0L.png) but then my image does NOT appear when viewing the web part from 
[THIS url (sharepoint)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjy3T.png)

Comment: This is where i got the tutorial to add the if/else statement in the gulpfile.js

https://blog.mastykarz.nl/correctly-reference-images-sharepoint-framework-solutions/

Answer (score 0):

My test result in my environment(SPFx 1.8.2, without changing gulpfile.js).

```
return (
      <div className={styles.reactSpFx}>

        <div className={styles.container}>
          Image Load
        <img src={require('../../assets/panda.jpg')} alt="test" />
```

[image]

[image]